# Is it possible to include dual table in a join query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to include the DUAL table in a join query ?

Can anyone give me an example which includes the `SYSTIMESTAMP` from dual table.

Comment: You should tag your questions with the specific kind of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 4):

One common use *(for me)* is to use it to make inline views to join on...

```
SELECT
  filter.Title,
  book.*
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Red Riding Hood'  AS title FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Snow White'       AS title FROM dual
)
  AS filter
INNER JOIN
  book
    ON book.title = filter.title
```

*[This is a deliberately trivialised example.]*

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can but there's no need to.
you can add the systimestamp pseudo column to whatever query you already have:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, systimestamp
FROM your_table t
```

Will give same results as

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, d.st
FROM your_table t, (select systimestamp st from dual) d
```

Note that the dual table has only one line, so the cartessian product will not add rows to your original query.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. A.B Cade's solution worked. The actual thing I am trying to do is as follows : When we hit a server using Fiddler or Postman for API testing, the DB returns event timestamp vaules. This timestamp value I need to compare to the webservice call return time stamp, i.e., the time stamp of the actual http web response. The endTime value. Is this value should to be included in the API itself by DEV or is there any way we can query something and get it ? And how to convert this timestamp to CDT ? I will open the new thread if this is not a relevant question. Thanks.

Comment: @rktimeless, I'm not sure that I understand your requirement but it seems as if you ought to open a new thread for this question. As for CDT, the `timestamp with timezone` datatype (as systimestamp) already supports the CDT, read more here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006760

Comment: Hi ABCAde, I just need to get the timestamp when a http web response returns. I am using Fiddler to hit the API to a server which successfully gives the http response like this :"header": {
        "product": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "version": "xxxxxxxx"
    },
    "status": {
        "elapsedTime": 329,
        "httpReturnCode": 200,
        "statusCode": 0,
        "success": true,
        "startTime": 1350387905444,
        "statusDescription": "Successful"
    },---this is the json response. But this doesn't show the endTime, the time at which the response returned.Any ideas?

Comment: @rktimeless, sorry but I still don't understand. Quering `select systimestamp from dual` will give you the DB timestamp, it has nothing to do with the http response time. I'm a DB person, I don't understand what you mean when you say *I am using Fiddler to hit the API to a server*. Open a new thread and tag your question so others that understand more will see your new question

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of systimestamp but was not sure how do I use it with my tables. Thanks for your help ABCade.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
 select (select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual ) as d
        /*
           Here you can add more columns from table tab
        */ 
 from tab
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to, `DUAL` keyword is a way of saying that you're not querying a table, if you want to "join" `DUAL` with an other table, just query the other table including your columns that don't come from the table in the select clause.

**EDIT :** As the comments says, this statement is false, **`DUAL` is a table.**

I still think there is no point in including (from the question)

> the DUAL table in a join

Comment: That's not true, `DUAL` is a table and not a **keyword**. Read more here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388

Comment: @A.B.Cade Right, my bad. Still `DUAL` is designed as a helper and as long you are including an other table in the query, there should be no longer any need for that helper. There is no point doing any cartesian product with a single row as it's the neutral element and the OP is clearly asking for "include the DUAL table in a join".

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this in Oracle. I found this question while trying to solve a similar problem. The trick is to wrap `DUAL` in a subquery, and return a static value which you can join on.

In my case, I wanted to see if a record meeting some conditions existed in a table before inserting a new record. If it existed, I wanted the `ID` column. If it did not exist, I wanted a new `ID` value from a sequence. I used `DUAL` to "fake" an outer join so that I would always get a row back. Then I used `NVL()` to return a sequence value if the result was null.

```
SELECT NVL(v.ID, REAL_SEQUENCE.nextval)
FROM (SELECT 1 as match FROM DUAL) d,
     (SELECT 1 as match, ID 
         FROM REAL_TABLE
         WHERE CONDITION = CRITERIA) v
WHERE d.match = v.match(+)
```